# Need a full screen background image to contain hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background-image

I have a landing page for a website that uses a full screen background image.  I need the "Enter Site" portion of the image to be clickable into the main site.  I tried using image map code, but the dimensions don't work properly on larger monitors.  Is there a way to make a full screen background image contain a clickable hyperlink so they can click anywhere on the page to enter?  Here's my current HTML:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<img alt="full screen background image" src="Dock-BG-ES.gif" id="full-screen-background-image">

<p>
<img border="0" src="map.gif" width="1440" height="813" usemap="#entermap">

<map name="entermap">
<area shape="rect" coords="730,560,1200,815" alt="Enter Site" href="welcome.htm">
</map>
</p>

</body>
```

And CSS:

```
html, body {
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#full-screen-background-image {
z-index: -999;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full page background use background-size css property:

```
 body {
   background:url('') no-repeat center center fixed ;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;   
 }
```

And then link

```
a {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Update:
**background-size doesn't work on IE8 and lower**

Comment: Done, tested, and it works perfectly in 4 browsers I tested (Chrome, IE, Firefox & Safari).  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

For full background use

```
html, body {
   background:url(/Dock-BG-ES.gif) repeat top left;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Use onclick event for making entire portion clickable

```
<body>
<div onclick="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make the whole image clickable. 
You could try to use a div and position it over the img using position:absolute. And % values for left and top. But this will fail with different side ratios of screens, unless your "Enter Site" is in a corner of the image.